get the wrong number of type=hidden in rails turbo-stream > template tags
I had a turbo-stream code:
<turbo-stream action="append" target="hidden-applicable-object-key">
  <template>
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <input type="hidden" name="items[my_keys][]" value="<%= item.id %>">
    <% end %>
  </template>
</turbo-stream>

When I tried to get the number of <input type="hidden">, it always get the wrong number.
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($("input[name='items[my_keys][]']").length);
});

For example, if the @items.count is 500, the console.log($("input[name='items[my_keys][]']").length) would got a random number which is smaller than 500 such as 402, 399, or 430.
Also, when I uploaded the record to server, the params[items][my_keys] would exactly the same number of console.log($("input[name='items[my_keys][]']").length) got instead of correct number.
Does anyone know how did this happend and how to solve it?

turbo stream doesn't reload the page, how exactly are you counting your inputs on document ready?

On document ready, I got the same wrong number.
I had also tried counting the the record once I press the upload button. It would get the same value.

how are you triggering the turbo stream? I just don't understand the workflow here. it works fine for me: i click a button > respond with turbo stream > count 500 inputs.
